# Amazon Rekognition Video is NOT detecting a specific person, but every one else works fine

Tags: boto3, amazon-kinesis, raspberry-pi4, amazon-rekognition, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm using rekognition video to detect faces in a stream coming from a raspberry pi 4. I use kinesis video stream with gstreamer plugin to send the stream from the raspi to the rekognition stream processor and then read the response from the kinesis data stream with python. Rekognition can detect and works just fine with everyone but my father. I tried creating an other collection and adding no one and rekognition detects everyone (does not recognize because the collection is empty) but my father.
I also tried a single face search response with an image of my father and it seems to work just fine but for some reason, with rekognition video it doesn't even detect him as an unknown.
It doesn't throw any error, it just does not detect him.